# Figure not displayed in pdflatex after exporting from lyx

Tags: lyx

I am able to add the figure in a lyx document, by using float and insert graphics. But when I view in the pdf, I don't see the figure in the inserted location. Instead I see the location of the file inside a blank box. See below.

[image]

I want to know why this is the case and any suggestions on how to fix it

Comment: Same question posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695249/figure-not-displayed-in-pdflatex-after-exporting-from-lyx. @triangular_triffle please link to any related (and especially duplicate) questions. Please think about the people spending their time to help you. They might spend 20 minutes to write up an answer to try to help you, and I don't think they would feel good if they knew there was already an answer. Sometimes it is helpful to post on multiple forums or Q&A, but please always link to them, so that everyone can see them.